# int.ToString(format) not inserting " literal

Tags: c#, .net-core, tostring

I have the following format `var format = "0\"";`

I then use it like this `1.ToString(format);`

I'm expecting it to return `1"` but it returns `1`

How do I make it insert the *double quote* (`"`)?

I have tried...

```
var format = "0\u0022";
var format = @"0""";
```

and can't get it to work.

It does work if I use `string.Format`...

```
var format = "{0}\"";
string.Format(format, 1)
```

that will give me `1"` as required.

Does anyone know how to get `.ToString()` method to *insert the double quote*?

Comment: Try `var format = "0\\\"";`

Comment: Wrap `"` in apostrophes: `1.ToString("0'\"'");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to add characters into format string as the *they are* (not as a *part* of the format string), wrap them into *apostrophes* `'...'`:

```
 // 0 - specifies format
 // '\"' - will be preserved as it is - " 
 string result = 1.ToString("0'\"'");

 Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 1"
```

Comment: ahhh thank you my man, I missed this the first time I read the Custom numeric format strings on msdn!!!